# Android WiFi-Direct BroadcastReceiver wont work

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I'm trying to connect to a WiFi Direct network using Nexus 4.

I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    WifiP2pManager mWifiP2pManager;
    Channel mChannel;
    WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        mWifiP2pManager = (WifiP2pManager)getSystemService(WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mWifiP2pManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

        ((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton_power)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("p2p", "discoverPeers() called");

                mWifiP2pManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d("p2p", "discoverPeers() Success");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reason) {
                        Log.d("p2p", "discoverPeers() Failure: " + reason);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mWifiP2pManager, mChannel, this);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

}
```

And the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private Channel mChannel;
    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel, MainActivity activity) {
        super();
        this.mManager = manager;
        this.mChannel = channel;
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        Log.d("p2p", "Action: " + action);

        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            Log.d("p2p", "Requesting for peers");

            if (mManager != null) {
                mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, peerListListener);
            }
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
        }
    }

    private WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {
            Log.d("p2p", "deviceCount = " + peers.getDeviceList().size());
        }
    };
}
```

When I click the button the `discoverPeers()` returns Success. However, I never get any of the broadcasts specified in the IntentFilter, when I start/resume the activity I get a few broadcasts:

> 02-26 16:19:08.684    7656-7656/com.example.app D/p2p﹕ Action:
>   android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED 02-26 16:19:08.684
>   7656-7656/com.example.app D/p2p﹕ Action:
>   android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE 02-26 16:19:08.684
>   7656-7656/com.example.app D/p2p﹕ Action:
>   android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED

But none of them are the one's I registered to the IntentFilter and for some reason  I get those 3 although they are not added to the filter.

**Edit:**
It seems I got confused with the name of the strings and they're actual value, I do receive some of the actions I added to the IntentFilter.

Comment: i would like to know, which android version you are using?

Comment: I am also doing the same and also facing the problem that only a few times `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` intent is broadcasted and sometimes it is not broadcasted.  Did u get the solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you are actually getting the correct results although they are not as you expected. When you p2p state change you are supposed to see "android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE" value. And same goes for other filters. Check this page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION

Comment: Yes, and im using Android Studio so I changed the sdk version in the gradle.build too

Comment: You are correct , it does show the correct actions I got confused there (see my edit). Please edit your answer and the comment you wrote so people won't think that the problem was in the permissions. Thank you!

Comment: I also have similar problem. But I could not understand the solution. Could you explain it further? I also could get any output from this line.  Log.d("p2p", "deviceCount = " + peers.getDeviceList().size());

Comment: i am also facing the same issue, could you please tell me how to solved it??.?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you are still following this however Google has added a note in the WifiP2p reference that sheds some light on this issue. (An issue that I was having as well)
Found here: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

```
         // Code for when the discovery initiation is successful goes here.
        // No services have actually been discovered yet, so this method
        // can often be left blank.  Code for peer discovery goes in the
        // onReceive method, detailed below.
```

From this note it appears that you will get the onSuccess() indication IF the discoverPeers() was successful BUT you will only receive the 'WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION' broadcast indicating that the list of available peers has changed IF there is an available peer to detect. I tested this with two smart phones running a wifiP2p app.

I hope this help, if at least you may find you answer in the google references.